# Combine Grep commands so I only list results from .pro files?

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I'm looking for any .pro file that contains the string "xxxxx.h"

I tried doing:

```
grep -Iir "xxxxx.h" . | grep "*.pro"
```

But that didn't work.  Is this even possible with just the grep command? If not, how else would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--include` option:

```
grep -Iir --include='*.pro' "xxxxx\.h" .
```